# Line breaks outside <?php tags

Tags: php

My web host's PHP engine is taking everything outside <?php ?> and replacing line breaks with <br>, like so:

```
<?php

echo 'php1';

?>

Hello
world

<?php
echo 'php2';
?>
```

The output I get is:

```
php1
<br><br>Hello<br>world<br><br>php2
```

All of the other servers I use do this, which is what I want:

```
php1

Hello
world

php2
```

Can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: So you should contact the hosting provider and request that they stop doing this? What is your question?

Comment: Well, your host kinda sucks. Not much we can do.

Comment: And for formatting other text apart from php echo code, you should use proper html tags. Hello world won't be breaked unless used <br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no [PHP `.ini` directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) to do this.

Contact your webhost and ask them about it, but I suspect that something else is up here.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header to Content-Type: text/plain and see if that helps

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
?>
```

Comment: That outputs plaintext to the browser (you see the source code instead of the formatted page) but the <br>s are still in there.

Comment: Yes, I know it outputs plaintext, but you didn't have any HTML in your example so I didn't know if you needed it.  But it didn't work anyway, oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your host is very wierd

```
<?php
    echo 'php1';
?>
Hello
world
<?php
   echo 'php2';
?>
```

Comment: No, that just outputs:
php1<br>Hello<br>world<br>php2

Comment: is this the *whole* of your PHP program?

Comment: ahhh right okay, sorry I miss read the question :P, okay, that's very wierd, check if there are any open tags, or anything with the rest of the script... if everything seems to be in order, try putting this above the whole code: `<?php header("Content-Type: text/html"); ?>` This should display the page, if it doesn't well, I dunno :P, wierd host of yours :D